# "The locations of the lobes of the lungs" - How to shorten it?

Tags: possessives

It's not comfortable for me to see two "of" in the sentence:

> "The locations of the lobes of the lungs"

Could I say "lobes' lungs"?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong, unnatural or unpleasant about two *of*s in a sentence.

Comment: The most economical solution is 'lung lobe location', but it doesn't seem like any improvement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *lobes' lungs* would be the *lungs of the lobes*. What you want is the other way round

> the locations of the lungs' lobes

However, that does not strike me as any sort of improvement over *the locations of the lobes of the lungs*. And frankly, I find the doubly threefold alliteration of **l**ocation**s**/**l**obe**s**/**l**ung**s** a lot more annoying than your two *of*s.

Rewrite. If you've already mentioned the lungs, delete them here: presumably anyone who reads your piece will know that if you've got lungs, they've got lobes. Or use a different word:

> the locations of the pulmonary lobes